# How to open "My Computer" using QFileDialog

Tags: c++, qt4, qfiledialog

Am using like this

```
QFileDialog dialog;
dialog.setDirectory("::{645ff040-5081-101b-9f08-00aa002f954e}");
```

Is there is any other way to open "MY Computer" ?

Answer (score 1):

I tried with `Qt 4.8` and:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QFileDialog diag(0, "A dialog");
    diag.setDirectory( "My Computer" );
    diag.setModal(true);
    diag.exec();

    return app.exec();
}
```

worked fine.

My system language is Spanish and using the `My Computer` string worked, so I think this will work with any other system language too.

Please note that the string **must be** "My Computer" or it won't work. So things like `My computer` or `MyComputer` are discarded.